# java android studio помогите

Tags: java, android-studio

помогите исправить ошибку пожалуйста

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.musicpleer">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MusicPleer">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <service android:name="com.example.musicpleer.MusicService"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Ошибка

```
ERROR:C:\Users\ilyas\MusicPleer\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:29: AAPT: error: unexpected element <service> found in <manifest><application><activity>.
```

Comment: Ошибка какая? Напишите хоть

Comment: ERROR:C:\Users\ilyas\MusicPleer\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:29: AAPT: error: unexpected element <service> found in <manifest><application><activity>.
 ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В манифесте service и activity должны быть внутри application. Это отдельные элементы.
В вашем случае вы должны вынести

```
<service android:name="com.example.musicpleer.MusicService"/>
```

за пределы `</activity>`, но перед `</application>`